# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildProfile'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

I am working on a flutter project trying to build an apk and it is giving me an error.

Here is the error code i am getting when i try to run app

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:83:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this   candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const Scaffold({
    ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
    context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildProfile'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

solutions i tried

*deleted pubspec.lock file and did pub-get

*invaledated cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's an issue with `chewie: 0.9.10`, the latest version of this package is available which is `chewie: ^1.0.0`, try with latest version.
After making change in `pubspec.yaml`, run `flutter clean` first and then try to build again.